# How should I condense many short bits of contract work for my CV / resume?

Tags: resume, hiring-process, contractors

What sort of options are available to the serial contractor who has worked on many projects for 4 - 9 months each and who would like to have a concise CV?

My CV currently features a work history back to May 2010 which comprises six entries (with between one and three lines for each). I have removed some of the smaller companies for whom I worked previously and omitted mention of cases of repeat work for the same company at different times. As it stands, my work history is fairly straightforward and intelligible. I can see that after a year or so -- assuming I continue to take up short contract work -- it will be too verbose and eat into the space I have for the rest of the document if I want to keep it down to 2 pages.

Are there any formatting techniques that deal with the issue of working for a large number of clients (sometimes working with the same at different times)?

I thought about grouping them by skills and technologies used but the chronology would then become hard to follow.

Comment: I have just spotted http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1263/how-can-i-improve-a-resume-to-avoid-looking-like-a-job-hopper which gives me some ideas to chew on: possibly to reduce older contracts to one-liners with no information except the company name, dates and job title. As pointed out in the related topic, employers will view contract work differently to permanent.

Comment: [This question](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/4423/2322) is nearly identical - my answer there seems like it would apply here, too. Is there a meaningful difference you want differently there?

Comment: Agreed. It is very similar and I might not have OP'd if I had seen the linked question. I think my phrasing of the question uses more keywords and that there is more chance of someone finding this if they want to see these suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How does the following sound?

> 2009 - 2010 - Multiple Clients
>
> Work focused on SQL Server reporting, using at various times SSRS, Microsoft Access, and C#/ASP.NET. ETL projects importing flat
>   files, CSVs, and spreadsheets to merge with existing database tables.
>   Functions coded in SQL Server for special case field transformations.
>   Clients were either small businesses or departments with little access
>   to IT resources - responsible for analysis and user interface as well
>   as solution development.